# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\insert_data.php on line 9

Tags: php

So I got this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\insert_data.php on line 9
```

On this line:

```
$std-id = $_POST['std_id'];
```

my php code is:

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['submitted'] ) )
{
include ('mysql_connect.php') ;

$std-id = $_POST['std_id'];
$std-name = $_POST['std_name'];
$std-year = $_POST['year'];
$std-degree = $_POST['degree'];

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO student ( ID , Name , Year ,  Degree ) VALUES (' $std-id ' ,   ' $std-name ' , ' $std-year ' , ' $std-degree ' ) ";

if (!mysql_query ( $dbcon, $sqlinsert ) ) {
die( ' error inserting new record ' ) ;
} // end of nested if statment

$newrecord = " 1 record added to the database " ;
} // end of the main if statement

?>
```

Comment: I guess John answered your question. This means that you'll have to replace all your dashes with underscores.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 7):

You can't have dashes in your variable names. [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

Comment: Interesting. Does this only apply to mysql related scripts?

Comment: @Fred It applies to all PHP variables at all times

Comment: Thanks John. Strangely enough, I've never used them, probably due to the fact I never liked dashes in the first place.

Comment: One thing I do remember though, is that one can't use 2 underscores in a row at the beginning, which I think are `magic` reserved functions, am I right?

Comment: actually, `${'std-id'}` would work, but don't tell the OP. On a side note, this is TL and a dupe.